# javascript string action unescaping Url.Action

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript code as follows

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "_id_", id2 = "_id2_", id3 = "_id3_", id4 = "_id4", ... })';
```

used in the ajax calls where *idxx* is replaced with other values
However the var url is generated with  "...&id2=*id2*&..." etc.
and i just learned that javascript string.replace() works only on the first occurance

wondering if there's another way to code the var url rather than replace multiple times ?

the solution has to be universally executable i.e. run in older browsers as well

Comment: this is within the past year, the solution has to work everywhere, updated the question

Comment: Please check this answer from same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/9695286. It has used `RegExp` which will work for older browsers as well.

Comment: that should work, does the &amp; need any special handling for regex ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Replace all which will replace all occurrences

```js
var test = 'id=_id&id=_id&id=test';
var replacedStr = test.replaceAll('_id','teststr');

console.log(replacedStr);
```

.

Comment: updated the question, replaceall is for newer versions within the last year